Cannot change the background color of Dropdown component
In my Blazor WASM project I am using a Dropdown component from Blazor Bootstrap. The component is part of a menu. In one of my pages I have a different background color of the body, but the dropdown inherits the color. How can I make it keep a consistent color in all pages?
I am changing the color of the body with a JSInterop on initialization of the page.
This is how I am changing the color:
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
     CurrentUser = authState.User;
     await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setCssVariable", cssVariable, cssValue);

 }

The dropdown looks like this, when I want it to be white:
enter image description here
I tried modifying the classes I found were put onto the component, but to no avail.
